# gedit installation size is too large

Tags: debian, gedit

have installed Debian Linux, but gedit is not installed along with it. When I attempt to install gedit using apt-get, it prompts to download many packages up to 370 MB, which is strange. I only want to download gedit in my gnome environmnet, and do not want to have a fresh install of the remaining installed packages like xorg-server, libwebkit, libboost,....

Do you have any idea how I can only install gedit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages Debian is trying to install are dependencies of `gedit`: without them, `gedit` cannot run.

Looks like apt-get wants to download the whole Desktop Environment i.e. the GUI.  Evidently you have a minimum install of Debian (without GUI) and now it's asking you for the additional packages: `gedit` is a graphical editor so it needs X Windows to run.

Most probably you don't want to install X, so you should rather use `nano`, `vim`, or other CLI text editors.